# ASP.NET SignalR WebSocket Close Timeout

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, signalr, signalr-hub

whats is the equvalent way to the asp.net core SignalR way to defined the WebSocket close time out

```
endpoints.MapHub<NotificationsHub>("/notificationsHub", confoptions =>
            {
                confoptions.WebSockets.CloseTimeout = TimeSpan.FromHours(24);
            });
```

in order defined the WebSocket close time out in ASP.NET SignalR (.NET Framework)

Comment: Setting a value like 24 hours seems like a really bad idea. Seems like you're trying to do something, but that setting doesn't do what you think it does. What are you trying to do?